# Cumulative sum in C is blowing up to infinity

Tags: c

I'm generally an R user but I am trying to use to C for some lower level cumulative sums and multiplications.

I am trying to generate a cumulative sum of **eta** and storing the result in **tmp0**. However, when I output **tmp0** it either gives me Inf, NaN, or some arbitrarily large number. I double checked the same cumulative sum in R and it works fine; I am not sure why C is not handling it. Below is the code that I am using:

```
   int i,j;
   const int p = ncov,  n = nin;
   double accNum0[n]; //accumulate first part of likelihood sum eta_i
   double accNum1[n]; //accumulate the backwards numerator
   double accNum2[n]; //acumulate the forward numerator (weighted)
   double tmp0 = 0;

  double eta[n]; //calculate linear predictor in this step (X %*% beta)
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < p; j++)
      eta[i] += b[j] * x[n * j + i];
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    tmp0 += eta[i];
  }

  return (tmp0);
```

Again, I am fairly new to C so I may be making some rookie mistakes and would greatly appreciate any (and all) suggestions!

Comment: This code is incomplete.  `b` and `x` are not declared, and `accNum0`, `accNum1`, and `accNum2` are unused.  Please update your question with a [mcve] that others can compile and run that reproduces your problem along with input, expected output, and actual output.

Answer (score 5):

There might be errors with how you are initializing `b` or `x`. However, one definite error is that `eta` is being used uninitialized. This means `eta[i]` may begin with some arbitrary value instead of `0` as you are likely expecting.

Add an initialization before accumulating into it.

```
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    eta[i] = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < p; j++)
      eta[i] += b[j] * x[n * j + i];
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that cleared it up. I thought that double eta[n]; would already specify the vector to be 0 but I guess that's not the case.

Comment: C requires explicit initialization for local variables. There is only implicit initialization to zero for variables with static duration (typically global variables).